# My car (has broken or broke) down, so I have to call a mechanic at once

Tags: tense, phrase-choice

> My car (has broken or broke) down, so I have to call a mechanic at once.

Should I use the Present Perfect or the Past Simple in this situation? I think the Present Perfect is more suitable because the effect is shown.

Answer (score 1):

British English uses 'broken down'.

Unsure if 'broke down' is considered to be grammatically correct in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine - like you say, the present perfect also implies it's having some effect on the current time (it's still broken, I have to take the bus, I'm late etc.) whereas *my car broke down* just says that the event occurred in the past (the rest of your sentence is enough context to know it's still broken and affecting the present though!)